# Saxon 9.7 and XMLBeans / XPath

Tags: xpath, saxon, xmlbeans

I'm trying to use XPath in my Web Application with Saxon 9.7.0-14 EE and xmlbeans-2.6.0 / xmlbeans-xpath-2.6.0

```
Movement mov = (Movement) XPathUtils.executeQueryNoResultNull(message.getPayload(), "//trx:Movement [@tipo='RESTO']");
```

with

```
public static XmlObject executeQueryNoResultNull(XmlObject source, String query) {
        XmlObject[] results = source.selectPath(DECLARE_NS + "$this" + query);
        if (results.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return results[0];
        }
    }
```

and I have this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:  Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying XDK... Trying delegated path engine... FAILED on declare namespace trx='http://www.test.com/xxx/xx/trx';$this//trx:Movement[@tipo='RESTO']
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:185)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:136)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._selectPath(Cursor.java:902)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.selectPath(Cursor.java:2634)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:476)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:460)
```

Is the problem XMLBeans ? Can I use only Saxon and remove XMLBeans ?

Here my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="app-common">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jsr173_1.0_api.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="resolver.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xbean_xpath.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="saxon9ee.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="saxon9-dom.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
```

Comment: That message usually indicates the Saxon classes aren’t being found. It’s worth double-checking to make sure the jar files are actually installed where  they need to be and that the names of the jar files in those `path` values in your `module.xml` match the actual names of the jar files in the filesystem. It may also be that you need to make sure the Saxon version matches whatever the XMLBeans docs say it should be.

Comment: The JAR files seems to be correct and I have them into the JBoss module directory. Looking here https://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq#whatJars seems that Saxon 9.7 is not supported from XMLBeans. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Here my JBoss modules directory http://imageshack.com/a/img924/9306/K0MIpI.png

Comment: In that image I notice that while all the other other jars have corresponding `.jar.index` files, there is no `saxon9ee.jar.index` file listed. That seems odd. Anyway otherwise that all looks like it matches the paths you have in the module.xml file. As far as whether Saxon 9.7 is supported by XMLBeans, the docs don’t explicitly say it’s not supported—instead they were just written before Saxon 9.7 existed. So it’s more like just the fact that they’ve not yet tested Saxon 9.7 with XMLBeans and documented that it works.

Comment: I also noticed that there isn't a file index for saxon9ee.jar but why ?

Comment: I also don’t know why it’s not generating that saxon9ee.jar.index for the fact that it’s not might indicate that jar is not actually getting loaded and deployed as expected, for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

With XMLBeans version 3.1.0, the most recent version of SaxonHE that I have used successfully is 9.2.1-5. Anything at version 9.3 and above triggers the error that you have seen, i.e. a failed attempt to find an XPath engine that can cope with a query with predicates. The XMLBeans docs [explain](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/guide/conSelectingXMLwithXQueryPathXPath.html) why the query works without the predicate:

> By default, XMLBeans supports only very simple XPath expressions. To
>   execute complex expressions — such as those with predicates, function
>   calls, and the like — you will need xbean_xpath.jar and the Saxon jars
>   (see below) on your class path.

With XMLBeans 3.x, you don't need to include xbean_xpath.jar (the classes are included in xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar), although the documentation has not yet been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on XMLBeans, but I wonder if the problem is that the "XPath" expression in question

`declare namespace trx='http://www.test.com/xxx/xx/trx';$this//trx:Movement[@tipo='RESTO']`

is not true XPath (because of the 'declare namespace') and therefore doesn't work with a third-party XPath engine?

Comment: This one for example works Movement mov = (Movement) XPathUtils.executeQueryNoResultNull(message.getPayload(), "//trx:Movement");   .... the problems seems to be "[@tipo='RESTO']"

Comment: What makes you think the problem is the predicate (which is valid XPath) rather than the namespace declaration (which isn't)?